# wx.Notebook tab only showing in cropped in top left corner rather than taking up the whole frame?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to test out the `wx.Notebook` `tabs` in one of my guis. However, I've got a problem where only a tiny portion of the tab shows in the top left corner.

[image]

As you can see, only a very small part of it is showing. I can't figure out what wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "test", size=(640,480))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT, size=(640,480))
        tabOne = wx.Panel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab One")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.PySimpleApp(redirect=False)
    frame = MyFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Anyone know what would cause such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix one line:

```
notebook = wx.Notebook(self, style=wx.BK_DEFAULT, size=(640,480))
```

Formerly you created the notebook as child of `panel` which hasn't any sizer set. Hence the small size. `panel` is now obsolete.